How to COUNT the depth of hierarchy?
I have a table employees as below:



id
name
managerId




1
Annie
Null


2
Bob
Null


3
Chloe
1


4
Danny
2


5
Eddie
3


6
Felicia
3


7
Georgia
4


8
Harper
3



Top-level management is Annie and Bob as they don't have managers above them (managerId is Null). I need to count the number of employees top-level managers are in charge. The expected output:



id
name
number of employees




1
Annie
4


2
Bob
2



Annie is the direct manager of Chloe, and Chloe is the direct manager of Eddie, Felicia and Harper, so the number returned is 4.
As far as I read, it seems I could try recursive query but I still don't know how to do. Or please tell me if there are better options. Thank you.

IMHO there are better structures to accomplish this. Maybe have a look at nested sets

Here how to do it using the recursive CTE :
WITH RECURSIVE employees_count (id, name, parent_id) AS (
  SELECT id, name, id as parent_id
  FROM employees 
  WHERE managerId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.id, e.name, ec.parent_id
  FROM employees_count AS ec 
  JOIN employees AS e ON ec.id = e.managerId
)
SELECT parent_id as ID, COUNT(*) AS nb_employees
FROM employees_count
WHERE id <> parent_id
GROUP BY parent_id

The nonrecursive SELECT produces the row for the top level managers (the row with a NULL managerId).
Each row produced by the recursive SELECT finds all employees who report directly to an employee produced by a previous row
Recursion ends when employees have no others who report to them.
Demo here

wow, I learn new thing....
reference for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/xHhFPXKF
